# Как на winforms добавить индикатор(кружочек) загрузки файла?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как на winforms добавить индикатор(кружочек) загрузки файла?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Создаете](http://ajaxload.info) или находите нужную гифку.
2. Добавляете на форму контрол `PictureBox`.
3. Устанавливаете гифку как изображение для контрола.
4. При начале загрузки файла делаете контрол видимым, после окончания загрузки -- прячете. Учтите также, что если контрол задизейблен, то анимация перестанет работать.

Естественно загрузка файла должна идти в отдельном потоке, иначе UI будет висеть и никакой анимации пользователь не увидит.

Comment: Это будет работать без создания отдельного потока для загрузки файла?

Comment: @AleksandrZharinov если вы будете грузить файл в UI-потоке, это с большой долей вероятности заморозит UI, поэтому толку от индикатора будет мало. Спасибо за наводку, обновил ответ.

Comment: @andreycha А в wpf можно использовать?

Comment: @SVD102 что использовать?

Comment: @andreycha Все что выше сказано.

Comment: @andreycha Как 4 пункт реализовать?